# Sorting column wise and get indices in Matlab?

Tags: matrix, matlab

I want to sort in Matlab the element of each row of a matrix `A` in a matrix `B` and obtain a matrix `C` reporting the column index of each sorted element in the original matrix `A`. If two elements of a row of `A` are the same the reported column indices should be in increasing order, e.g.

```
A=[3 2 1 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 0 10 2; 2 1 1 0]
B=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 0 2 9 10; 0 1 1 2]
C=[3 2 1 4; 1 2 3 4; 2 4 1 3; 4 2 3 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin `sort` function will do this, when ran on rows (dimension 2 in Matlab).

First output will be the elements sorted within each row giving `B`
Second output will be the column indices of the elements of B from A within each row giving `C`

```
[B,C]=sort(A,2)
```

or if you just want `C` replace `B` with `~` in the above line..